# Linq dynamic Where clauses by string

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

i have some problem with universal method in C#, i have 4+ model classes like this:

```
public class Assortment{
     public string Code { get; set; }

     public string EANCode { get; set; }

     public float Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

i want to create universal logic method liek this ->

```
public T GetItem<T>(int someInt, string expression) where T : class
{
     return db.Set<T>().Where(expression).Select(x=>x);
}
```

is this posible?

Comment: Yeah, but in a lot of cases it's just kicking the can down the road, and making life harder work all the while

Comment: You will regret it. If you want to do something generic, return an IQueryable<T> and let the caller build their own expression and select statement (ie: return db.Set<T>().AsNoTracking();)

Comment: What is the purpose of `someInt` in your method? Instead of `string expression` how about `Expression<Func<T,bool>> expression`?

Comment: If you must, consider using [DynamicLINQ](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core).